# Android admob interstital not loaded if not used with a banner

Tags: android, admob, android-2.3-gingerbread, banner, interstitial

I am currently trying to integrate admob trough Google services in an Android app, but I am experimenting a strange and annoying problem, on my real device (a 2.3 Nexus One) : My interstitial is not loaded EXCEPT if I also have a banner, of which load  request is triggered after the interstitial request.

- If I do that, everything works fine, and the ads load almost right away (I also have the success logs).
- If I do not exactly do that (adView.loadAd(bannerAdRequest) must be invoked after interstitial.loadAd(interstitialRequest), and I cannot simply get the adView or create its request without triggering it), the interstitial is never loaded, and I end up (after many seconds) having the logs
  "Timed out waiting for WebView to finish loading" and "Failed to load ad: 2". Of course clicking the button meant to display the interstitial does nothing as interstitial.isLoaded() returns false.

My device is 2.3 (in English US) connected by wifi, no adblock, app min target is 1.9, target is API 13 and I compile using API13 (I also tried using API 19). Last version of Google play services. It works fine on a 4.4.2 emulator. I have of course created both the banner and the interstitial in the add mob console, and added my own device as a test device using new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice. I also tried sending a new request after the first one fails (in the listener) but it does not work either.

If this never worked I could think I forgot something primordial, but this behaviour is really strange. As if the second "small" request was somehow pushing the "big" one.

Edit: I have tested on a 2.3 emulator with a big screen and everything works perfectly. On a "small" emulator I have a warning log stating "Could not parse mediation config: {"ad_networks":[{"adapters":["com.google.DummyAdapter"]," etc etc, but this emulator is 320*240 px, so I guess ads are not properly supported on such small sizes.

Edit 2: If ad loading fails, I also have big performance problems in the app (which uses OGL) and I can see additional logs, especially this one "Jit: resizing JitTable from 8192 to 16384", which seems to indicate there is something unusual going on.

Edit 3: The Google sample located in the JDK does not work either for interstitial, it loads forever and then I have the same time out problem and "Failed to load ad: 2". I notice that I happen to have a log stating D/webviewglue(330): nativeDestroy view: 0x46c728 before the crash, this may cause the problem (but this occurs even with the sample). And if I change the xml layout for banners to put the id of my banner ad, I can now launch the example, display the banner ad, go to the interstitial example, and now it loads and is displayed properly.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using the same AdUnitId for both banner and interstitial. They need to be distinct.

Comment: Yes they are distincit

Comment: Ok, so everything started to work properly without me doing anything. Perhaps AdMobs servers were having problems, or my phone was having a cache trouble or something like that. Nevertheless I am a little concerned by the fact that this may come back, especially considering the performance bug that occured. I have investigated this before it being solved, and it was due to the webviewcorethread that had tons of CPU usage. Unfortunately I did not have time to see which method was doing that. But it was a big stack, not the classical wait on a message queue.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue and posted this in another thread. i found this post just now.
here is the link of mine thread
[Google Play Service: Ad loading issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648950/google-play-services-ads-loading-issue)

I have few fixes. may be you can try and think upon. but still its not as stable as stanalone admob SDK.

Can you please share the proper fix if you got any??

Comment: I had already seen people have problems when displaying both, but mine is somehow the opposite : the ads did not work if I had not both a banner and an interstitial. Perhaps the problem is related, as if requests were interacting (in the good way for me, in the bad one for you). Unfortunately my problem suddently got solved without me doing anything (as if it had been a admob server problem) so I have no fix for you. If I find any more information I will provide it to you.

Comment: Mine is working fine too. Fix? i have to load Interstitial in asynch task. thats all.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this is to create a new ad unit on admob and use that id instead