# Google Play Services: Ads loading issue

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

**Description:-**
I am integrating my App with "Google Play Service" SDK as per latest guidelines from Google.
earlier it was integrated with standalone admob SDK.

**ISSUE:-**
Banner ads and Full ads are shown properly when one of them are shown. But when both has to be shown, they give unpredictable results.

Unpredictable results?
Yes, sometime only Banner is loading and sometime only Full ad is shown. it is very rare that both of them are shown.

**FIX:-**
1. I tried giving some delay between Banner and interstitial and got little better results. But still results are unpredictable most of the time.

1. I used Asynch task for Full ads. Gave some delay of 2 seconds in Background() and loaded the ad in PostExecute(). It give much better results. But still out of 10 attempts, only 7 times both the ads are shown. rest of the 3 times either Banner or Full or none of them is loaded.

Following is the code of **Main activity**

```
package com.example.adtest_new; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
Context myCont=null;
private InterstitialAd interstitial = null;
AdRequest adr;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myCont = this;

    //--------------BANNER AD----------------------------------     
    //Locate the Banner Ad in activity_main.xml
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView); 
    // Request for Ads
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build(); 
    // Load ads into Banner Ads
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    //--------------BANNER AD----------------------------------         

//Fix-1 (Did not work)
    try{Thread.sleep(2*1000);}catch(Exception e){}          

//Fix-2 (Did not work)
//Called Asynch task here(put delay of 2 seconds in background() and loaded full ad in postexecute())

    //--------------FULL AD----------------------------------   
    //Prepare the Interstitial Ad
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);        

    //Insert the Ad Unit ID
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-465697675827xxxx/xxxxxxxxxx");
    adr = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    //Load ads into Interstitial Ads 

    //Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() 
    {
        public void onAdLoaded() 
        {
            //System.out.println("!!! Full Ad loaded  !!!");
            Toast.makeText(myCont, "!!! Full Ad loaded  !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Call displayInterstitial() function
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });        
    interstitial.loadAd(adr);    
    //--------------FULL AD----------------------------------   
}    

public void displayInterstitial() {
    // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) 
    {
        interstitial.show();
    }
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/openedWindows"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/completePath"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:text="/mnt/sdcard"
    android:textColor="#ff2d8df1"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans"/>

<View
android:id="@+id/bar0"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:background="#ffb2cb39"    
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>



<View
android:id="@+id/bar1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:background="#ffb2cb39"    
android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>


<RelativeLayout     
android:id="@+id/temp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"   
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/selectAll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_green"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:text="BUTTON1"
    android:paddingLeft="10px"  
    android:paddingRight="10px"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/selectBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_green"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:text="BUTTON2"
    android:paddingLeft="10px"  
    android:paddingRight="10px"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>


<View
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_above="@+id/tableRow2"
android:background="#444444"    
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>

 <TableRow
 android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     ads:adSize="BANNER"
     ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-465697675827xxxx/xxxxxxxxxx"
     />    
</TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.adtest_new"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

**Kindly let me know how to resolve this??
Standalone admob SDK is working fine for both of the ad types.**

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are loading "real" ads (ie not test ads), as you do not declare test devices. I am not 100% sure about what I am going to say, but this could perhaps be the cause of the problem. When displaying real ads, I think you will not always have available ads from Admob/Google Play Services, so sometimes you will not have ads displayed (I think the loading error code is 3, which is "no fill"). You could test while declaring test devices, which cause the use of test ads that are always available.

In addition it is recommended to use test devices while developping, because if you click a lot on your own ads (by mistake or just to test) you may be banned from AdMob.

To see how to add test devices, cf this

> Test ads
>
> You should use test ads during development to avoid generating false
>   impressions. Additionally, you can always count on a test ad being
>   available. Set up test ads by passing your hashed Device ID to
>   AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice:  AdRequest request = new
>   AdRequest.Builder()
>       .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
>       .addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4")  // My Galaxy Nexus test phone
>       .build();
>
> logcat will print the dev
>
> ice's MD5-hashed ID for convenience, for example:     Use
>   AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4") to
>   get test ads on this device.

(https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/banner)

Take care that some people say that test ads do not work properly if your phone is not in English ([AdMob test ads shows only on English devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382029/admob-test-ads-shows-only-on-english-devices))

Edit : Of course real users of your app will use the real ads, so they may also experience the "problem" of not always ads available, but this is normal. You can still regurlarly Schedule new loads (for the interstitial, the banner reloads itself regularly) to try to cope with that I guess.

Edit 2 : By the way, this may be a little irrelevant to your problem, but people usually strongly advise to no display the ad from the AdListener.onAdLoaded method, but to invoke this manually at the moment your want it to be displayed (if isLoaded is true). But this is only an ergonomy consideration, no a bug-Wise one